# Is this a sufficiently robust method of validating a password for a sign up page?

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have the following function which runs onBlur of the password text field in my Username & Password sign up form.

Every time the user clicks outside of the password field, I want to run this function to make sure the password they entered meets the following requirements:

- Is 6-30 characters in length.
- Doesn't contain any whitespaces (at the start, middle or end of the string).

.

```
function checkPassword(){
   console.log("checkPassword is running...."); 
   var haswhitespace == 0;
   var userpassword = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;

   if (/\s/.test(userpassword)) {
      var haswhitespace == 1;
   }

   if(userpassword.length == 0 || haswhitespace == 1){
      alert("Password can not be empty, or contain spaces.");
   }
   else if (userpassword.length < 6 || userpassword.length > 30) {
      alert("Password must be between 6-30 characters long");
   } else{
      console.log("Password is okay, so now we enable the Sign Up button.");
   }
}
```

My question is, is this the correct method to handle password checking? It looks too simple to be correct to me, and I'm not sure if that's the correct way to check for all possible types of white spaces?

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give to improve this function.

Comment: You will need to repeat the test on the server since it is simple to do `window.checkPassword=null;` before submitting. Is "........" a valid password?

Comment: That is the correct way to check for a whitespace, as long as you _only_ want to do it for user information purpose. As @mplungjan it's trivial to bypass that check, so don't rely on this being the one and only password validation.

Comment: Your code appears to handle the requirements you have stated.  Simple isn't bad. :)

Comment: This question might belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On a further note, unless this is just a personal training excercise, I'd strongly suggest not putting an upper limit on length. Passwords _should be_ hashed, most likely salted and hashed before storing them - an upper limit on length is meaningless and it only serves to reduce password strength.

Comment: @OcuS Code Review deals only in working code. The author doesn't appear to be convinced the output is correct, which would land it in a bad spot for the Code Review [guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My password is `` , is it supposed to fail or pass the test?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan can you elaborate on what you mean? This check will only be used to make sure that the user's chosen password meets the requirements before I enable the "Sign Up" (which will then create a user account for them), is this not secure/is there a way they could send an invalid password to my database through this method?

Comment: Hi @georg I just want to make sure the password is between a certain length and doesn't contain any empty spaces. But would there be any security issues with allowing code tags/emojis to be used in username/password fields? I'm hashing & salting the passwords in a php file before they get entered into my database, but would allowing emojis cause an issue with that process?

Comment: If you do not check again on the server you can have this scenario: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Emily: just wanted to point out that the `.length` of the above string will be `6` and not `3` as you probably expect.